# parse src link from iframe response received from a post request

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, beautifulsoup

Im making a post request with data in python like this

```
select_req = req.post('https://www.example.com/payment/', data=data)
print(select_req.text)
```

this outputs

```
<iframe class="paymentFrame" src="https://www.google.com/hpp/pay.shtml" width="100%" height="400"  scrolling="yes" frameborder="no"></iframe>
```

I want to parse the src link and save it to parsed_link

```
print(parsed_link)
```

I want this to output 
https://www.google.com/hpp/pay.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect css class selector to be faster method

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(select_req.text, 'html.parser')
parsed_link = soup.select_one('.paymentFrame')['src']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
html_doc = select_req.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
link = soup.find('iframe').get('src')
```